# How to delete a DataGridView row that is being added when the user cancels the addition process?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a databound `DataGridView`. When a new row is added and the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> I want to delete the entire row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

quite easy actually

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)27)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
            MessageBox.Show("Last row deleted!");
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**but take in mind that:**

> Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove rows from the DataGrid, you have to use a BindingSource instead of a list, otherwise you will get an exception when doing it.

try this:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form {

  private BindingSource _source = new BindingSource();

  public YourForm() {
    List<Model> list = _service.GetList();
    _source.DataSource = list;
    _grid.DataSource = _source;
  }
}
```

Now you can play around with your datasource and the grid will behave itself. Don't forget to call _grid.Refresh() after each change.

Cheers,

Andre carlucci

Answer (score -1):

Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the `DataGridView` is data-bound to an `IBindingList` that supports change notification and allows deletion.